# Fourier transform of $e^{j 2 \pi f_c t}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm studying the communication book from Haykin. In the book, the author states the following,

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iu6j.png)

How is that transform correct? Isn't the fourier transform of that exponential equal to $2\pi \delta (w-w_0)$ = $ 2\pi \delta (2 \pi f - 2\pi f_0)$

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

No idea of what you are doing, $e^{2i \pi a t}$ is not $L^1$ nor $L^2$ nor a compactly supported distribution so we can't compute its Fourier transform by direct integration, we need the Fourier transform of distributions.

The Fourier transform of $e^{2i \pi a t}$ is $\delta(f-a)$ because  for all $\phi \in L^1$ the Fourier transform of $\phi(t) e^{2i\pi at}$ is $\hat{\phi}(f-a) = \hat{\phi}(f) \ast \delta(f-a)$. Equivalently the inverse Fourier transform of the compactly supported distribution $\delta(f-a)$ is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(f-a)e^{2i \pi ft}df=e^{2i \pi at}$.

Comment: $\mathcal{F}\ ( e^{jw_0t})\ = 2\pi \delta(w-w_0)$. If we substitute $w_o = 2\pi f_0$,  $\mathcal{F}\ ( e^{jw_0t})\ = 2\pi \delta (2\pi f - 2\pi f_0)$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes you are, what is $w-w_0$, what convention is using the table you are referring to, why don't you try to follow my answer